# SQL Filter based on Multi-Row Security

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, filter

We are currently using MS SQL Server 2005, but will soon be migrating to 2012 (or 2014).
I am facing the following scenario.

data table (data)

```
id   | location | group  |  level
-----+----------+--------+---------
1    | loc1     |   A    |    1
2    | loc1     |   B    |    5
3    | loc1     |   A    |    9
4    | loc1     |   A    |   12
5    | loc2     |   A    |    1
6    | loc2     |   B    |    5
```

And this security table (security)

```
user | location | group | level from | level to
-----+----------+-------+------------+----------
u1   | loc1     |   A   |    1       |    5
u1   | loc1     |   A   |   10       |   15
u1   | loc2     |       |    4       |    9
```

The logic is that each value of one row in the security table is concatenated with "and" (if not null), each row with "or".

Currently I build the where clause dynamically in a stored proc as a simple string. This works fine with small number of security rows defined for a single user, but will take ages for 5000+ rows.

Example:

```
select id from data 
where location = 'loc1' and and group='A' and level>=1 and level <=5
location = 'loc1' and group='A' and level>=10 and level <=15
or location = 'loc2' and level>=4 and level <=9
```

-> id: 1, 4, 5, 6

I do not see any way to do this on SQL side in a smart way.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: That's a pretty smart way for the requirements you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select distinct id from data
Inner join security on data.location = security.location 
And data.group = security.group
And data.level between security.[level from] and [level to]
```

The distinct part is to prevent duplicated result give out from query

Comment: Thx, that works for the example I gave initially. However, that made me realize that I should add one row. With the updated example, this will unfortunately not work anymore (I think).

Comment: Added some more details. I think that should better refelect the scenario now.

Comment: I added one more line of code. Anyway i personally think you should add one row for each security level. Its easier to monitor how many people are in a certain security level.

Comment: Ya, it makes sense in this example. The actual data goes up to 1000 and there are users having access from 0 - 1000 though. I didnt try your example, but that will not work for the "wildcard" I guess. If I have 10000 locations and I want someone to have access to all of them, I currently just leave the locations column null.